# Complex vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I work with this vector: `vector<string, vector<int>>`.
I supposed that the first iteration returns an array:

```
for (vector<string, vector<int>>::iterator it = sth.begin(); it != sth.end(); ++it) {
    // how do I get the string?
    // I tried (*it)[0], but that did not work
}
```

Also, how would I `push_back` to this vector? Passing `vector<string, vector<int>()>()` did not work for me. Thanks

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do? why is vector<int> used as allocator? I'm missing something fundamental in your logic....

Comment: You cannot create a vector with two types. What you want seems to be a map. Or you need to create a vector of std::pairs

Comment: This is wrong in several ways. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm simulating a hash map behaviour, where the string is the key name. But is works somehow different and that is why I didn't uses hash map in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vector takes:

- first template parameter is a type
- second optional parameter is an allocator

`vector<int>` is not a valid allocator for string.

Assuming you do not want map here, you probably want:

```
vector< pair<string, vector<int> > > outerVec;
vector<int> vecInt1, vecInt2;
vecInt1.push_back( 1 );
vecInt1.push_back( 5 );
vecInt2.push_back( 147 );
outerVec.push_back( std::make_pair( std::string("Hello World"), vecInt1 ) );
outerVec.push_back( std::make_pair( std::string("Goodbye Cruel World"), vecInt2 ));
```

If we typedef things:

```
typedef std::vector<int> inner_vectype;
typedef std::pair< std::string, inner_vectype > pair_type;
typedef std::vector< std::pair > outer_vectype;
```

Now iterate:

```
for( outer_vectype::const_iterator iter = outerVec.begin(), 
      iterEnd = outerVec.end();
     iter != iterEnd; ++iter )
{
    const pair_type & val = *iter;
    std::cout << val.first;
    for( inner_vectype::const_iterator inIter = val.second.begin(),
          inIterEnd = val.second.end(); inIter != inIterEnd; ++inIter )
    {
        std::cout << '\t' << *inIter;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Should hopefully output something like:

```
Hello World    1    5
Goodbye Cruel World   147
```

Comment: Seems like I missed the `pair`. Thanks